# How to bind service to fragment in android

Tags: android, android-intent

How to bind service to fragment in android. It returns false when tried to call bind service in fragment.

Comment: You could bind it in your FragmentActivity and make the `service` variable public and then set in your Fragment constructor

Comment: @tolgap: what are you talking about?

Comment: The same way you bind to an activity http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Answer (score -1):

You can do it programmatically, first you create your `BroadcastReceiver` then you register to it from the `Fragment`. `getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter)`

Comment: How does this bind a Service to a fragment?